# Numpy Divide Arrays With Multiple Out Conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, division

I have two, two-dimensional arrays (say arrayA & arrayB) that are exactly the same size (2500X, 1500Y). I am interested in dividing array A by array B, but have three conditions that I would like to be excluded from the division and instead replaced with a specific value. These conditions are:

1. If arrayB contains zero at point (Bx,By), replace output (Cx,Cy) with (arrayA*arrayA)
2. If arrayA contains zero at point (Ax,Ay), replace output (Cx,Cy) with 0.50
3. If both arrayA & B at overlapping points (Ax,Ay & Bx,By) contain 0, replace output (Cx,Cy) with 1

I've found that numpy.divide parameters `out` and `where` allow me to define each of these individually, so I've taken the first condition and arranged it as follows:

```
arrayC = np.divide(arrayA, arrayB, out=(arrayA*arrayA), where=arrayB!=0)
```

My question is how can I combine the other two conditions and their desired outputs within this operation?

Comment: I believe your conditions if stated explicitly is
1. if element in B is zero and A non zero
2. if element in B is non zero and A is zero
3. if element in B and element in A are both zero

Comment: @Kartoos, that is correct - much more succinct to help those fielding answers to this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution, not sure it is the fastest

```py
za=A==0
zb=B==0
case0=(~za)&~zb
case1=zb&~za
case2=za&~zb
case3=za&zb
C=case3*1 + case2*0.5 + case1*A*A # Case 3,2, 1
C[case0]=(A[case0]/B[case0])
```

Could be more compact with less intermediate values, but I've chosen clarity.

You could also use a cascade of np.where

```py
zb=B==0
C=np.where(A==0, np.where(zb,1,0.5), np.where(zb, A*A, A/B))
```

Edit: better version (but still not perfect)

```py
zb=B==0
za=A==0
C=np.where(za, np.where(zb,1,0.5), A*A)
np.divide(A, B, out=C, where=(~zb)&~za)
```

It combines np.where and your np.divide where=
It is as fast as the previous solution.
And does not complain about 0-division, since division occurs only for the cases where it is needed.
Nevertheless, it computes the first version of C (the one before np.divide), and particularly A*A, everywhere, even where it is not needed, since it will be overwritten.
So, it could probably be better.

Comment: I follow the logic here - I'd prefer to use use a cascade of np.where if possible, might make the operation cleaner to follow locally. Let me test and verify this works as expected before accepting your answer!

Comment: The second version is faster (just timeit'ed it; it's 30% faster) than the 1st. But it has one disadvantage: it complains about 0 division. Because A/B is computed everywhere, even in places where the result will be discarded

Comment: After running this locally, I am accepting your answer, particularly the third version that avoids complaints with 0 division. I appreciate your help!